# Does governor limits apply for declarative tools like workflow rules, process builder and flow builder

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, workflow, governorlimits

If I have a trigger for a account object when record is created or updated using process builder how the trigger will work when bulk of records are inserted into the org.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to add detail of the research you have done and to add where you are stuck. As it stands, this question doesn't meet community requirements and will likely be closed without answer.

Comment: You should read about [flow bulkification](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=0).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, governor limits apply to declarative tools:

- [Per-Transaction Flow Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_limit_transaction.htm&type=5)

> Autolaunched flows are part of the larger transaction that they were launched through and share that transaction’s limits. For example, flows launched from Apex or a process are executed with the Apex or process actions as part of the larger transaction. Flows with Screen elements can span multiple transactions. A new transaction begins each time the user clicks Next in a screen.

- [Process Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.process_limits.htm&type=5)

> Processes are governed by the per-transaction limits that are enforced by Apex. If a process launches other automation in the same transaction, that automation shares the process transaction’s limits. If the process or its launched automation causes the transaction to exceed governor limits, the system rolls back the entire transaction.

If you have a trigger and declarative process that run on insert/update for a specific object, they will [be executed in the following order](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm):

- Executes record-triggered flows that are configured to run before the record is saved.
- Executes all before triggers.
- Executes all after triggers.
- Executes workflow rules. If there are workflow field updates, before and after update trigger will be executed one more time.
- Executes the following Salesforce Flow automations, but not in a guaranteed order: Processes, Flows launched by processes, Flows launched by workflow rules.
- Executes record-triggered flows that are configured to run after the record is saved.

So, if a process builder create a new case and there is a before or after insert trigger on Case object, it will be executed in the same transaction, therefore if a governor limit is exceeded, the whole transaction will be reverted.